# Django running wrong view method

Tags: django, django-views

I have to view files stored in mysite folder. one is named as views.py and other is named as request_view.py. In urls.py, I have used 'answer' method for views.py and 'display_meta' method for request_view.py.

(django version: 1.5 and python version: 2.7.3)

this is the url pattern:

```
url(r'^twitter/$', answer), url(r'request/$', display_meta)
```

when  I call http:/127.0.0.1:8000/request/, then also first view(i.e. /twitter/) is called!

any help?

one more thing. In my view.py, I have some unbounded code (i.e. the code which is neither present in a method or class). can this be the cause of the problem?

```
l = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, l)
keyword = input('enter the keyword you want to search for?')
stream.filter(track = [keyword])
```

apart from this code, evry code is either in the class or method.

One thing that I noticed is that first the code of the view.py runs, then display_meta runs.

Thanks in advance.

**SOLVED**

The problem was with the import function that I was using. since my code was unbounded in one of the views, the import function always import that regardless of the url that I choose.

**Suggestion**

Always use the nomenclature mentioned in the this [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#example). In many books it has been suggested that we should import the views, but it might cause an error if you have **unbounded code** like I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly why /twitter/ view is called, but I can see two things to change:

1. You should use a string as the second parameter for url(), as you can see in this example [1]. You can use 'myapp.views.my_method' nomenclature.
2. You forgot to start the request URL with ^ that indicates the start of the URL.

About the unbounded code, I don't know if that could be causing the problem. But I can't see why are you putting that code unbounded. I am not sure when that code would be executed, I guess the first time you call a view in that file and Django loads the file (I'm guessing, I don't know exactly), but I don't think that would be a good way to do that. Think when do you want to execute that code, put it in a method, and call it.

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#example

Comment: Thank you so much! :) problem solved! 
although the exact problem was of the use of 'import' function.

Comment: I'm glad :) Maybe when you wrote url(r'^twitter/$', answer), the answer method were being called and django didn't continue searching the right url. In any case, problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

HI hemant i am wondering why you have written `request_view.py.`

Please see the django docs.

what you can do is .

Create two function in your `views.py` like

```
def answer(request):

   do some stuffs.

   render_to_response(template.html)
```

and on the same page write another

```
def display_meta(request):

   # do your studd
   render_to_response(some.html)
```

YOU NEED NOT TO CREATE TWO SEPERATE `VIEWS.PY`

I dont know what this code does

```
l = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, l)
keyword = input('enter the keyword you want to search for?')
stream.filter(track = [keyword])
```

But if you want to use `StdOutListener`  inside your function you can call in your view

like

```
def display_meta(request):
   stobject  = StdOutListener()  # use parameters if you have here 
   # do your studd
   render_to_response(some.html)
```

Comment: hi, I use 'from mysite.request_view import display_meta'. I thought using this command will help me importing this function (display_meta) from the file request_view.py
The reason why I used this another file is that in views.py I have a different code and jst don't want to mix my practice codes with it.
so, wat u suggest?

Comment: alternatively you can put this code in some other file and import and start using that class or function in your views   Please check how Django MVT works first

Comment: actually these two functions have nothing in common! display_meta is just a practice example given on "djangobook.com". the answer method is for my project work. 
I know I should create a different project for practicing but this error made me think how to resolve such errors.

Comment: It's simply not true that urls.py will only look in views.py. It doesn't care where the view functions are, only that they are properly referenced in the urls.

Comment: @Daniel: that's wat I was saying/doing! ne idea wat's happening here?

Comment: @Hemant not with the information you've provided. You'll need to show the full urls.py at least. And I agree with masterofdestiny in that I've no idea what you're doing with that "loose" code.

Answer (score 0):

Organizing views into a python package could solve this problem. So if you have a structure like this...

```
# views.py
def SomeView(request):
    return HttpResponse('SomeView')

# another_view.py
def AnotherView(request):
    return HttpResponse('AnotherView')
```

Your can reorganize these separate view files into a views package. That is...

```
# views
    # __init__.py
    from views import SomeView
    from another_view import AnotherView

    # views.py
    def SomeView(request):
        return HttpResponse('SomeView')

    # another_view.py
    def AnotherView(request):
        return HttpResponse('AnotherView')
```

And now, everything can be called in a django-standard way:

```
url(r'^url-to-some-view/$', 'views.SomeView'),
url(r'^url-to-another-view/$', 'views.AnotherView'),
```

UPDATED:

To make a 'python package'...

1. Create a `views` directory at the same level as the `view.py` file [`mkdir views`]
2. Create a `__init.py__` file inside the `views` directory # this is what makes a directory a 'python package'
3. Move `views.py` into the `views` directory.
4. Move your `request_view.py` into the `views` directory.
5. Edit the `__init__.py` file with the necessary import statements. In this case:

   ```
   from views import answer
   from request_view import display_meta
   ```

What this does is replace a file with a directory. By importing everything into the `__init__.py` file, this directory looks like a large file to your code, rather than another module.

Comment: hey. Thanks for the help.. can u pls tell me how to create this package?